# Powershell: Compress files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-3.0, powershell-1.0

I need to compress files based on the month and year they were written.

```
# group files based on extension month/year
$groups = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\mypath -filter "*psv.*" | Group-Object {"{0:MMMM} {0:yyyy}" -f $_.LastWriteTime }

# compress groups
ForEach ($group in $groups) {
    & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u ($group.FullName + ".7z") $group.FullName
}
```

The script above isn't working, however, When I run the following line alone

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\mypath -filter "*psv.*" | Group-Object {"{0:MMMM} {0:yyyy}" -f $_.LastWriteTime }
```

I get the following result which is fine.
[image: result]

However, it isn't zipping the group of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$groups = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\mypath *psv.* | Group {"{0:MMMM}-{0:yyyy}" -f $_.LastWriteTime}
foreach ($group in $groups) { 
    foreach ($file in $group.Group.FullName) { 
         Write-Host "Processing " + $group.Name + " " + $file 
         & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u ($group.Name + ".7z") $file
    } 
}
```

The Group property of the GroupInfo object output by GroupInfo contains all the files that are in that grouping.  You have to enumerate those files.